# Commerce removing customers

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

Is it possible to remove commerce customers? I removed users, but customers stay and I don't see any options to remove them in the control panel.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to remove customers from the control panel.

However, you can use a console command to cause a garbage collection run. This will remove any customers not associated with a user account or cart/order. It will also do all the things a garbage collection run will do.

docs for craft 3x
https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/gc.html